# Jquery click event doesnt work

Tags: jquery, angularjs, events, click

`Click` event doesn't work... use Angular with `Jquery`, have multiple click events in the file, but this one particular doesn't work

```
<ul class="phone-tumbs">
    <li ng-repeat="img in phone.images" class="additionalImgs">
        <img ng-src="{{img}}" alt="possible images" />
    </li>
</ul>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".additionalImgs").click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No no errors, when paste the code into the console, it works, when do it from editor, it doesnt

Comment: This example works https://jsfiddle.net/aesL4jjh/

Comment: There's a good chance your angularjs hasn't executed by the time jquery tries to attach the event handler.

Comment: @JAT yeap it does...

Comment: @Jack possibly to put .on(click)...

Comment: how can I attach the event handler after the Angular is done loading...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this "the angular way":

```
<ul class="phone-tumbs">
    <li ng-repeat="img in phone.images" ng-class="{fadedout: img.fadedout}" ng-click="img.fadedout = true">
        <img ng-src="{{img}}" alt="possible images" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

In your css

```
li{
transition: opacity .5s;
}

.fadedout{
opacity: 0;
}
```

Or actually use ng-show and ng-animate: http://www.nganimate.org/

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you try it like this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".phone-tumbs").on('click', '.additionalImgs',function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Comment: no it didn't I tried with binding before, it really got to work cause it binds it after everything is loaded but for some hell reason it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem.

Your code is fine, [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrvuknk3/)

The problem, like one of the comments mentioned, is that angular hasn't finished rendering the element.

You can see this by running the jQuery function right above your click function. You'll see the length is 0.

```
console.log($(".additionalImgs"));
```

So now you have to find a way to delay the binding of your click event until you know the element is actually there.

Unfortunately this is an area that Angular doesn't handle very well. You can read more about it in [this feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734)

The first thing I always try is using $timeout. It waits until the end of the digest cycle to fire it's callback code, even if you leave the time empty

```
$timeout(function(){
     $(".additionalImgs").click(function() {
          $(this).fadeOut();
     });
});
```

This blog post has a nice solution, creating a directive that fires a callback when the last ng-repeat element has been rendered. http://www.nodewiz.biz/angular-js-final-callback-after-ng-repeat/

The easiest solution to this particular problem is to use `ng-click` on your `ng-repeat` element.

```
<li ng-repeat="img in phone.images" ng-click="somefunction();" class="additionalImgs">
```